# elasticsearch - max_map_count vs Heap size

Tags: memory, elasticsearch

I am using the official elasticsearch docker image. Since ES requires a certain level of memory mapped regions, (as [documented](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/max-size-virtual-memory-check.html)), I increased it using

```
docker-machine ssh <NAME> sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

I also read [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#heap-sizing) that the memory allocated should be around 50% of the total system memory.

I am confused about how these two play together. How does allocating more memory mapped regions affect the RAM allocated. Is it the part of the RAM, or is it taken above the RAM allocation for elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2):

To sum it up very shortly, the heap is used by Elasticsearch only and Lucene will use the rest of the memory to map index files directly into memory for blazing fast access.

That's the main reason why the best practice is to allocate half the memory to the ES heap to let the remaining half to Lucene. However, there's also another best practice to [not allocate more than 32-ish GB of RAM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#compressed_oops) to the ES heap (and sometimes it's even [less than 30B](https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-heap-of-trouble)).

So, if you have a machine with 128GB of RAM, you won't allocate 64GB to ES but still a maximum 32-ish GB and Lucene will happily gobble up all the remaining 96GB of memory to map its index files.

Tuning the memory settings is a savant mix of giving enough memory (but not too much) to ES and making sure Lucene can have a blast by using as much as the remaining memory as possible.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question. I am confused about the memory mapped locations. ES wants it to be at least 262144. What would it mean to increase it or decrease it? What is the size of each memory mapped area? Does it vary with the ram of the machine?

Comment: The default value of `vm.max_map_count` is 65536 and ES suggest to increase it to at least a four-fold value instead (hence 262144). Obviously, increasing it would allow Lucene to get hold of more virtual memory to map index files, and decreasing it has the reverse effect (increasing the chances of swapping). Memory mapped areas are not the same as physical RAM (and hence not part of it), they are simply areas on disk (or anything that can be referenced with a file descriptor) that are considered **as if** they were in physical memory. The main idea behind that is to increase the IO perf.

Comment: Also this answer might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384759/vm-max-map-count-and-mmapfs/38404766#38404766